# Angular 2 Observable always returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am always getting undefined in my component code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If I try to write in console it returns 'undefined' .

I am using Angular2 and using Visual studio code as editor. 
Below is my service and component code -

```
**Service Code** 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs'

export interface GitHubUser
{
  html_url:string;
  avatar_url:string;
  login:string;
  score:string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GitHubServiceService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { 
  }

  getGitHubData(_searchTerm):Observable<GitHubUser[]>{
    return this._http.get<GitHubUser[]>
    ("https://api.github.com/search/users?q="+_searchTerm);

  }
}
```

Component Code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GitHubServiceService,GitHubUser } from './git-hub-service.service';
import {filter,switchMap,debounceTime,distinctUntilChanged, } from 'rxjs/operators'
import {FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  users:GitHubUser[];
  data$:Observable<GitHubUser[]>;
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private _githubService:GitHubServiceService){
       this.data$= this._githubService.getGitHubData('greg')
       this.data$.subscribe(users=>this.users=users)
       console.log(this.users);
       console.log(this.users.length);
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the value too soon. The request to search was most probably not finished by the time you print the value to console.

Try to print that in subscribe:

```
this.data$.subscribe(users=> {
   this.users=users;
   console.log(this.users);
   console.log(this.users.length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's not the case. If I use this - subscribe(data=>console.log(data)). I am able to print all in console.

Comment: Well, I beg to differ - that is *exactly* the case. See the difference (and similarity) between your code in question, mine in reply and your in the comment.

Comment: Adding to what @PeS mentioned, this is the function decription of subcribe(next, error, complete). It has three callbacks next(), error(), complete(). In an asynchronous execution scenario your console.log outside subcribe() will run before a response could be arrived from the http call. Thats y you should put console.log in the next() part of the callback. here next is "users => {}"  part.